# Is U.S CHEETOS HARAM OR HALAL

Tags: halal-haram, food

I want to know is hot Cheetos haram to eat or halal because I recently downloaded an app that tells where foods are halal or haram is called scan halal anyways it said that  U.S hot  Cheetos are haram cause the have enzymes but it also said that these enzyme are from beef not pork so I want to know why is it haram if the enzymes are coming from beef can somebody plz tell me is it’s halal or haram caz I’m so confused here by the way these are U.S Cheetos so its khosher

Comment: All meat has to be slaughtered according to Islamic guidelines to be halal. Just because the animal is halal to eat doesn't mean you can eat its meat without slaughtering correctly!

Comment: I would like to elaborate on @TheZ comment. Since it contains meat, we do not know who is slaughtering the beef. Beef is only halal to us if it is done by Muslims and is also allowed if done according to the people of the book (Christians, Jews).

Comment: Cheetos are not kosher, except in Israel, for precisely the reason you mention (beef enzymes).

Answer (score 1):

Alcohol may have been used as a solvent and the product is not halal certified so it is best to refrain from consuming it. Furthermore, I don’t necessarily think that all Cheetos are kosher certified as it is. There is a wide variety of crips or as you say in the US “chips” that are halal just choose wisely and hopefully you would find something else that you may like.
If you wish to contact them visit this website: https://www.cheetos.ca/contact-us

Just check the ingredients of the Cheetos in case they change and become suitable for a Muslim diet.